# Why POST method not working in spring boot

Tags: post

I'm trying to build a shopping cart app. I get error 404 when I'm trying to add the product to cart.

- Get request that retrieves the list of the products seem to work just fine.
- I also did a post to save a new product and that worked too.
- I tried adding @ResponseBody to addProductToCart  method, but that didn't change nothing.
- When I press add to cart buttom the url looks something like this http://localhost:8080/products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1. It gets the right the id of the product, but it gives 404 error.
- I tried disabling csrf, but that didn't work either
  Bellow is the code, messages from the log and the html for the products page
  **product controller**

@RequestMapping("/products")

public class ProductController {

```
 @Autowired
 ProductService prodService;
 
 @Autowired
 CustomerRepository custRepo;
 
 @Autowired
 ProductRepository prodRepo;
 
 @Autowired
 CartRepository cartRepo;
 
 @Autowired
 CustomerService custService;
 
 @Autowired
 private IAuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

 @Autowired
 CartService cartService;

@GetMapping
public String displayProducts(Model model) {
    List <Product> products = prodService.listAll();
    
 
    model.addAttribute("products", products);
    
    
    Authentication authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();
      Customer currentlyLoggedInCustomer = custRepo.findByFirstName(authentication.getName());
     //System.out.println(products.toString());
    System.out.println(currentlyLoggedInCustomer);
    //System.out.println(currentlyLoggedInCustomer.getCart());
    return "Products/productsList";
}


  @PostMapping(value = "products/add/{id}/{qty}", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public String addProductToCart (@PathVariable("id") long productId,
        @PathVariable("qty") Integer quantity,
          Model model) { 
      
      Authentication authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();
      Customer currentlyLoggedInCustomer = custRepo.findByFirstName(authentication.getName());
      
      Product productToBuy = prodService.listById(productId).get();
     
      model.addAttribute("productToBuy", productToBuy);
      System.out.println(productToBuy);
      productToBuy.setQuantity(quantity);
      model.addAttribute("productToCart",productToBuy);
      System.out.println("Customer " +authentication.getName()+" bought" + quantity + " "+ productToBuy.getName());
      
      cartService.addToCart(currentlyLoggedInCustomer, productToBuy);
 return "redirect:/products";
 }
  
  @GetMapping ("/new")
  public String getProduct (Model model) {
  Product product = new Product();
  model.addAttribute("product",product);
  return "Products/new-Product";
```

}

```
  @PostMapping ("/save")
  public String addProduct (Model model, Product product) {
      
      prodRepo.save(product);
      return "redirect:/products";
  }
  
@GetMapping(value = "/update/", produces = "application/json")

    public String updateProduct (@PathVariable (name = "id") long id,
            Model model) {
        
    Product product = prodService.listById(id).get();
    model.addAttribute("product",product);
        return "Products/new-Product";
        
}
```

}

**security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select first_name, password, enabled from customer where 
first_name = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select first_name, role from customer where first_name = ?")
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptEncoder);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
.ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**")
.ignoringAntMatchers("/products")
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/add/?id=", "/update/**")
.hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/", "/**")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin();
    
    //.disable()
            //.cors().disable().authorizeRequests()
           
            //.anyRequest().permitAll();
            

}
```

}

**html**

Add To
                                            Cart

```
                                </form>
```

**This is a part of the log**

1. /products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1 at position 10 of 14 in
   additional filter chain; firing Filter: '
   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.266 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
   /products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1 at position 11 of 14 in
   additional filter chain; firing Filter:
   'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.266 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  :    SecurityContextHolder
   not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained:
   'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb67582a:
   Principal:
   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@4bf4425:
   Username: Safta; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true;
   AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
   AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: USER; Credentials:
   [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:
   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId:
   F9E99D723894C8AAA4D9CD080C551F4E; Granted Authorities: USER'
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.266 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
   /products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1 at position 12 of 14 in
   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.266 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
   /products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1 at position 13 of 14 in
   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.266 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
   /products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1 at position 14 of 14 in
   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'

   POST "/products/products/add/?id=2&qty=1", parameters={id:[2],
   qty:[1], _csrf:[2ff325cc-2d99-4eee-b3e4-47b2fc0a2e7f]},
   headers={host:[localhost:8080],
   [JSESSIONID=793A49C0A4B6A04CDE7A632A78580153]} in DispatcherServlet
   'dispatcherServlet' 2021-04-13 21:08:37.269 TRACE 2088 ---
   [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped
   to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler
   ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
   "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]] and 4 interceptors
   2021-04-13 21:08:37.272 DEBUG 2088 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
   o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found

   "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error?id=2&qty=1", parameters={id:[2],
   qty:[1], _csrf:[2ff325cc-2d99-4eee-b3e4-47b2fc0a2e7f]}, ....

Is it related to the security filters? I m stuck on this for 2 weeks.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JFortun/CredentialManagerBackend
Here you can see a simple working CRUD API REST made with Spring to compare with yours.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link. I still haven't solved it. I removed security and I get error 404. My post method for adding a new product works, delete method works, but update doesn't work and post for adding a product to cart gives error 404. I don't get why as my html files are on the right classpath and I name my packages properly...I checked the thymeleaf link and that is right also. It is written in the same way I did it for delete method which works.